# Angular 2: ngx-popover close by hitting ESC key

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, popover

I am refering this ngx-popover in component

[ngx-popover](https://github.com/pleerock/ngx-popover) Question is now how I can close the popover by hitting ESC key

Here is my code

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 1em;" class="comment" *ngIf="myPopover2">
                        <popover-content #myPopover2
                                         placement="left"
                                         [animation]="true"
                                         [closeOnClickOutside]="true" [ng2-draggable]="true">
                            <button class="button_close" (click)="myPopover2.hide()">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <comment></comment>
                        </popover-content>
                    <button [ngClass]="{'container-element': myPopover2}" type="button" (keydown)="CloseEvent($event)" class="btn btn-labeled btn-default btn-block button_style" [popover]="myPopover2">
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  popoverVisible: boolean = true;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {}

  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) { // 27===ESC
      this.popoverVisible = false;
    }
  }
```

and then on the popover-element: `*ngIf="popoverVisible"`

Comment: Thanks....It worked but even my button is getting disabled, I want only the popover need to be close..

Comment: *ngIf adds/removes an element to/from the DOM. you need to place it in whatever element you want to remove or be displayed. if the popover is one element (button and tooltip-dialog), you can use CSS with `:host /deep/ .container-element name-of-the-tooltip-selector { visibility:hidden; }` to hide it (not remove from the DOM though, but this should be good enough for you). then you do on the container-element `[ngClass]="{'container-element': popoverVisible}"`

Comment: Still button element is getting closed with popover, I have shared my code please verify...

Comment: use *ngIf="myPopover2" in the tag which you want to hide on close. so in your case <comment> i guess